# How can I re write this code in the correct "react" way

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the innerhtml of an element in react, my solution is obviously not ideal since i'm manipulating the DOM directly. How can I write this in the correct way? Would it be better to useState or useRef? Basically, if plus is selected then turn into minus and if minus is selected then turn into plus. Each button is unique and there are multiple buttons

```
function App() {
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

const displayScores = (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == "+") {
      e.target.innerHTML = "-";
    } else {
      e.target.innerHTML = "+";
    }
  };


return (
    <>
{tags.filter((t) => t.studentEmail == students.email).map((tag, index) => {
                      return (
                        <p key={index} className="student-tags">
                          {tag.value}
                        </p>
                      );
                    })}
                  <input
                    onKeyDown={addTag.bind(this, students.email)}
                    className="student-tag"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Add a tag"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <button onClick={displayScores} className="expand-btn">+</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
</>
)
}
export default App;
```

Comment: First of all, I have to say there are some easier approaches to solve your issue, like using state value as the content of your button, which is currently provided by answers. But there is some important note here that you have to consider, **working with `innerHTML` or other similar properties does not mean that you access them through the actual DOM**, keep in mind `onClick` is a custom event which is implemented on the virtual DOM, so working with its `event` will still be like working on virtual DOM. So there is nothing to worry about actual DOM here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to access the DOM for this at all. You could use some React state (boolean) that determines if scores are displayed, and then render a "+" or "-" in the button based off of that boolean.

```
// Your state
const [scoresDisplayed, setScoresDisplayed] = useState(false);

// Function to update state
const displayScores = () => {
    // Toggle the boolean state
    setScoresDisplayed(state => !state);
};

// Conditionally render button text
<button onClick={displayScores} className="expand-btn">
    {scoresDisplayed ? "-" : "+"}
</button>
```

Comment: I thought of a similar solution, but that takes me back to the unique part. With this solution, every button will be effected onClick, not the unique button you've selected.

Comment: Abstract all of that logic into a reusable Button component that has it's own internal state. Then each use of the Button will still be unique and won't share state

Comment: awesome, I had no idea it worked like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in React you should not work with something like inner html,there much better ways like below :

```
 function App() {
      const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
      const [buttonLabel, setButtonLabel] = useState("+");
      
      const toggleButtonLabel = () => {
        setButtonLabel(buttonLabel === "+" ? "-" : "+");
      };
    
      return (
        <>
          {tags
            .filter((t) => t.studentEmail == students.email)
            .map((tag, index) => {
              return (
                <p key={index} className="student-tags">
                  {tag.value}
                </p>
              );
            })}
          <input
            onKeyDown={addTag.bind(this, students.email)}
            className="student-tag"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add a tag"
          />
    
          <button onClick={toggleButtonLabel} className="expand-btn">
            {buttonLabel}
          </button>
        </>
      );
    }
    export default App;
```

Comment: This causes the same problem mentioned below, while it works, it changes every single buttons label on the page. How can I make it unique to each button press like I did with e.target?

Comment: in your question there is one button , can you edit your q with multiple buttons?